# Are there any constants in the .NET framework for the different web method types (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD)?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, constants

I just noticed while creating a RESTful WCF service that the Method parameter on the `WebInvoke` attribute is case sensitive (CAPS required).

So,

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "Delete")]
```

is not equal to

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE")]
```

This mistake was causing a `ProtocolException`:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.

I was wondering is there a set of constants in the .NET framework that I should be using in place of "DELETE" in the above example.  I could of course define my own set of constants, but if feels like something that probably exists in the framework and I am just missing it.

Comment: I wish I could give another up-vote for the Silverlight update (I maintain libraries for Silverlight 2); roll your own, I guess...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A bit indirect, but there are `System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http` constants:

```
public const string Connect = "CONNECT";
public const string Get = "GET";
public const string Head = "HEAD";
public const string MkCol = "MKCOL";
public const string Post = "POST";
public const string Put = "PUT";
```

but no "DELETE" - suggest you make your own...

Annoyingly, there is a `System.Web.HttpVerb`, but it is `internal`, so not usable - and it is an enum, so to use the name in an attribute you'd need a bit of hackery.

Comment: Strange that they didn't put something in the System.ServiceModel.Web namespace.

Comment: FYI for anyone reading this answer, these constants do not exist in Silverlight

Comment: do we/u have any leverage to make this a connect.microsoft request, in that namespace, sorry not to make this a meta Q/comment.:)

Answer (score 0):

The System.Web.Mvc namespace has HttpVerbs.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpverbs(v=vs.118).aspx
The reference can be selected under Assemblies, Extensions